# Why I can not use scala MATCH in this way?

Tags: scala

I want to format a java object(real type can be bool number string) to com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive. and I tried two ways below, can somebody tell me why first is invalid and second works. (I guess because the return type of scala match is inferred as AnyRef or java.lang.Object, but this is not a valid type for JsonPrimitive's constructure, the second return type for scala match is inferred as JsonPrimitive, and this can be assigned to val jsonPrimitive. Is my guess correct? Thanks.)

Object o = new Integer(0);

> This can NOT work

```
val jsonPrimitive = new JsonPrimitive(o match {  
  case n: Number => n
  case b: java.lang.Boolean => b
  case s: String => s
  case _ => throw new Exception...
})
```

> This works

```
val jsonPrimitive = o match {  
  case n: Number => new JsonPrimitive(n)
  case b: java.lang.Boolean => new JsonPrimitive(b)
  case s: String => new JsonPrimitive(s)
  case _ => throw new Exception...
}
```

Comment: The inferred least upper bound is `Any`, but your guess is essentially correct. Since you've already provided a solution with a rather detailed explanation, it's not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It would be `Any` if `b` was `Boolean`, as it is it should be `AnyRef`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey and Alexey
I just want to confirm that my guese is correct or wrong. I thought that scala compiler could handle this dynamic type params and it maybe could generate jvm byte code dynamicly for match case, and actually it's not, it would not pass compile stage.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Oh... I thought it's the least upper bound of Scala's `Boolean` and `String`, that would have been `Any`. Missed the `java.lang.` parts. Ok, then the question contained a *completely* correct explanation of what's going on. Voted for "Problem resolved in a way that's unlikely to help any future users."